# Is it supported to pass the second argument into the toBe matcher of Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine

I found this code snippet from Angular's document, but cannot find this usage from Jasmine's docs. Is this really a supported feature? I just want to make sure that if I use this feature it will not break unexpectedly when upgrading to a newer minor/patch version.

```
expect(masterService.getValue())
.toBe(stubValue, 'service returned stub value');
```

Answer (score 5):

The supported method since 3.3 is withContext: https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html#withContext

```
expect(masterService.getValue()).withContext('service returned stub value')
.toBe(stubValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

The second optional argument of `jasmine.Matchers.toBe` (named `expectationFailOutput`) is the message to be displayed when `expect` fails. Regardless of not appearing in the [Jasmine documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html), it is really supported and exists on most methods of the interface `jasmine.Matchers`.

```
interface Matchers {
    ...
    toBe(expected: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    toEqual(expected: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    toMatch(expected: string | RegExp, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    toBeDefined(expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    toBeUndefined(expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    toBeNull(expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    ...
    toBeTruthy(expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    toBeFalsy(expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    ...
    toContain(expected: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    toBeLessThan(expected: number, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    toBeLessThanOrEqual(expected: number, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    toBeGreaterThan(expected: number, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(expected: number, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    toBeCloseTo(expected: number, precision?: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Important Update:**

I found passing in the second argument doesn't work for .toEqual() although it works for .toBe(). I'm using `jasmine` 2.8.16, haven't tried on other versions.

I also found these relevant threads:

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/641

https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/2752

So now I have changed my mind and would recommend NOT using this feature in your project. If you really want to use it, at least double check to make sure it works with all the needed matchers in your `jasmine` version.

**Original Answer**

I found an explanation of this in a different place in Angular's docs, although I still don't see it in Jasmine's docs. With @uminder's response together I feel most likely it's fine to use it. Feel free to give more updates if anyone has anything else to add.

> The second parameter to the Jasmine matcher (e.g., 'expected name') is an optional failure label. If the expectation fails, Jasmine appends this label to the expectation failure message. In a spec with multiple expectations, it can help clarify what went wrong and which expectation failed.